# jupyter notebook NameError: name 'sc' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I used the jupyter notebook, pyspark, then, my first command was:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4])
```

Then, it showed that

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c540c4a1d203> in <module>()
----> 1 rdd = sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4])

NameError: name 'sc' is not defined.
```

How to fix this error 'sc' is not defined.

Comment: Did you import `SparkContext`? It's not clear how your PySpark kernel is loaded.

Comment: I used the terminal, first change to the root of my spark, then type pyspark in terminal to load spark.

Comment: PySpark loads a spark context. Jupyter doesn't unless you set it up to do so

Comment: I have the same problem ,finally I find that because of the python version is wrong

Answer (score 7):

Have you initialized the `SparkContext`?

You could try this:

```
#Initializing PySpark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

# #Spark Config
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("sample_app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: I acted like you said. After I run sc = SparkContext(conf = conf),  it showed:         ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once;

Comment: There might have been other instances of Spark running. I suggest you kill all the sessions and try again.

Comment: what  KartikKannapur suggested fixed my similar issue.
thanks,  KartikKannapur!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
# #Spark Config
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("sample_app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

myrdd = sc.parallelize([('roze', 60), ('Mary', 80), ('stella', 34)])
```