# sc is not created automatically in notebook

Tags: data-science-experience

A notebook I created yesterday in DSX has stoped working - errors re can't find the sc object

```
"NameError: global name 'sc' is not defined"
```

I restarted the kernel but can't get it created. I have no other kernel running.
I created a new notebook - Spark 2.0 with Python 2 and literally nothing in it except:

```
sc
```

And that comes back as blank. I am expecting details on my SparkContext object.  In case I am going mad I double checked [docs](https://apsportal.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/creating-notebooks.html) and it says it should be automatic:

> The SparkContext and SQLContext are created for you as sc and
>   sqlContext respectively

Has something changed or anyone know how I can get the sc created in DSX?  Hope I'm missing something obvious. I tried the SparkContext function as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515369/jupyter-notebook-nameerror-name-sc-is-not-defined) but get an NPE.

Comment: If you don't have access to the Jupyter logs, then you don't have any chance to understand why the kernel fails to create properly. Full stop. So dig into the IBM documentation and/or contact their support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a glitch in the Spark service your notebook kernel wants to connect to. Please contact DSX support. There is a support button on the bottom right of each page.

Comment: It's working again, thx.  I didn't contact support, it fixed itself.